# I'm trying to get my forms to use (flex box) space-around, but it is not working in flex box

Tags: html, css, iframe, flexbox

[image][image: This is what it looks like and I want them to be centered with space around]
First image is what I want, second image is what I have.
*Please ignore the text in the image

I have tried applying~ flex: 1 1 auto; Onto both iframes and it doesn't change anything to no surprise.

I've tried to wrap the iframes into divs and change the classes to those divs, but both divs just wrap down to a new row.

I've also tried to use justify content center instead of space around, but there is no effect on the iframes

I made the iframes very small to better see the box's and there spacing

that's why this is the current code I am working with.

html~

```
<div class="book-club-box">

      <iframe class="sign-up-form" src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdIMTKQWGzsgaaKoMXMdwH-aWCYGt4_nkBR5PladQk71PBBzg/viewform?embedded=true" width="40" height="47" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>

      <iframe class="recomendation-form" src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdVwxefk0fq6NV3H-EryEfLk83_RQHUM-eVwav_gNmWL2-u8Q/viewform?embedded=true" width="40" height="47" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>
  
  </div>
```

css~

```
.book-club-box{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around; 
}

.recomendation-form{
}

.sign-up-form{    
}
```

Comment: When you apply `flex-grow: 1` to a flex item, it consumes all free space on the line. Hence, `justify-content: space-around` will do nothing, as it has no free space to work with.

Comment: What layout do you want to achieve? How items should be placed? Could you post an image? One images costs one hundred words

Comment: I took your advice and added a picture of what it looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that frames should be placed at start, so just remove `justify-content` property as it by default is set to `normal`.

An example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.book-club-box{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.recomendation-form {
  width: 30%;
}

.sign-up-form {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="book-club-box">

    <iframe class="sign-up-form"
      src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdIMTKQWGzsgaaKoMXMdwH-aWCYGt4_nkBR5PladQk71PBBzg/viewform?embedded=true"
     frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>

    <iframe class="recomendation-form"
      src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdVwxefk0fq6NV3H-EryEfLk83_RQHUM-eVwav_gNmWL2-u8Q/viewform?embedded=true"
      frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>

  </div>
```

**UPDATE:**

[What is the use of asterisk (*) selector in CSS ?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-use-of-asterisk-selector-in-css/#:%7E:text=The%20asterisk%20(*)%20is%20known,the%20elements%20on%20the%20page.)

> The asterisk (*) is known as the CSS universal selectors. It can be
> used to select any and all types of elements in an HTML page. The
> asterisk can also be followed by a selector while using to select a
> child object. This selector is useful when we want to select all the
> elements on the page.

**UPDATE 1:**

If you want to have space around, then use `justify-content: space-around;`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.book-club-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.recomendation-form {
  width: 30%;
}

.sign-up-form {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-club-box">

    <iframe class="sign-up-form"
      src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdIMTKQWGzsgaaKoMXMdwH-aWCYGt4_nkBR5PladQk71PBBzg/viewform?embedded=true"
     frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>

    <iframe class="recomendation-form"
      src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdVwxefk0fq6NV3H-EryEfLk83_RQHUM-eVwav_gNmWL2-u8Q/viewform?embedded=true"
      frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>

  </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the margin: 0; and Box-sizing: border-box are for.  But even with that this revised code did not work. I added an image to the original question and that is what it looks like after the revised code.

Comment: Firstly thank you very much for helping you seem to really want to help me. Unfortunately this still has no affect on the boxes and there is no justify-content: space-around in this code, but even when I add it it doesn't work

Comment: I'm so sorry I wasn't clear. That image is how they look now, which is not what I want. I want them to be centered with justify-content space around. I tried to alter the image to make it look the way I want it.

Comment: @Wayne you can show schematically what you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231386/discussion-between-wayne-and-stepup).

Comment: @Wayne Have you found a reason why it did not work?

Comment: Yes, embarrassingly it was because I had not linked the style sheet, I'm really sorry. Thanks for showing me that I needed to give them a defined size.